# Algorithm for smooth alpha crossfade?

Tags: algorithm, math, alpha

My application fades between various media and text layers by adjusting their alpha values. However, when using a linear crossfade the brightness appears to "dip" halfway through and then fade back up. After some searching I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3462002/3294329) that explains the issue, however the suggested solution, fading only one layer at a time, won't work for me since most of the layers I use already contain transparency.

[Here's an example of the issue I'm having, in HTML/CSS (code below because SO requires it](https://codepen.io/isaacsmith/pen/yJKxJY).

```
<style>
body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

.example {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}

#example1 {
    background-color: red;
    animation: 1s linear 0s fade infinite alternate;
}

#example2 {
    background-color: red;
    animation: 1s linear 1s fade infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: 0;}
  to {opacity: 1;}
}
</style>


<div id="example1" class="example"></div>
<div id="example2" class="example"></div>
```

The two divs should fade their opacities back in forth, resulting in a solid red image the entire time. Instead, it appears to dip in brightness.

What is the algorithm or formula for creating a smooth crossfade using alpha? I'm using OpenGL, if that's relevant. (The HTML/CSS snippet was just the easiest way of demonstrating the issue).

Comment: So how do you display transparent regions? That's the color you need to blend to. Or yet better. Also blend the alpha channel.

Comment: The transparent areas have alpha set to 0. I'm only adjusting the alpha channel, not any of the others.

Comment: It seems, you might just want to use `GL_CONSTANT_ALPHA` and `GL_ONE_MINUS_CONSTANT_ALPHA` for the blending function. And specify the fading time with `glBlendColor`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but it's not possible.

First off, the equation you want is defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/746937/6621180). I'll copy it here in other terms:

```
outputColor = overAlpha * overColor + (1 - overAlpha) * underColor
```

If I understand your question correctly, you're looking for a periodic function `f(t)` for your alpha transition such that:

```
1 = f(t - 1) + (1 - f(t)) * f(t - 1) = f(t - 1) + f(t) - f(t - 1) * f(t)
```

The only function that satisfies that equation, at least [according to wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f(t)+%2B+f(t-1)+-+f(t)*f(t-1)+%3D+1) is the constant 1. And that won't work if you want it to be zero at the beginning, and have it loop infinitely.

Unless you don't want a periodic function, and you just want your fades to look kinda nice. The equation linked above.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I ended up using a cubic bezier timing function like CSS uses for animations, it looks good enough for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

There is some good discussion of this topic at [this other question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/119380/the-perfect-crossfade).

It's true that there is no perfect solution, other than a step function, but you can mitigate the effects somewhat. The important thing is to have easing functions that cross at a relatively "high" point, rather than at 0.5. See graphs at [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/437908/62421).